# JAVA:-Converting Object Stored in HashMap to sql Date Type

Tags: java, date, jdbc, classcastexception

I have this problem..
I have a Hashmap containing the String as the key and Object as the value. I have one Date Object inside it...
While setting in the value for stored procedure call to DB I want to convert it to sql Date type..

Code Snippet..

```
this.cStmt.setDate(15,(java.sql.Date) (SubsProfile.get(Constants.SUBSC_DETAILS_EXPIRY_DATE_1)));
```

However while running I am getting ClassCastException..

Exception:-

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

please help me to convert it to appropiate type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because, as the exception says, your object is java.**util**.Date, and you're casting it to java.**sql**.Date!

Do this:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(((java.util.Date)SubsProfile.get(Constants.SUBSC_DETAILS_EXPIRY_DATE_1)).getTime());
this.cStmt.setDate(15,sqlDate);
```

Comment: while extracting value from hashmap i cannot use .getTime() because its an object and you cannot invoke getTime on object...!...

Comment: cast it to the appropriate type then. see updated code snippet above.

Comment: also consider using generics if applicable.

Comment: I guess it is working...I will see if I am able to insert value in DB..Thanks for the great help....

Answer (score 1):

get the long value of the java.util.Date object you have and create a java.sql.Date object using that long value.

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();

java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());

This should help you convert util.Date to sql.Date

Comment: HashMap extraction results in an object....since my hashmap is of type <String,Object>...